# How to clear RecyclerView when updating data?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I have a RecyclerView with a ListAdapter. The list that is shown in the RecyclerView comes from a Flow that is observed in the Fragment that the recyclerView is instantiated.

When the Fragment is created, the data are calculated too (in onViewCreated Method) .
In the first data-calculation the RecyclerView is empty, a progressBar is shown, then the data is calculated, the progressbar hides, and the RecyclerView is populated.

If I go again in this Fragment to re-calculate the data, the previous list is shown simultaneously with the progressbar, and then is updated.

I want every time that new data is calculated to NOT show the previous list (just like the first data-calculation), but can't find a way to do it.

I tried to clear() the currentList and notifyDataSetChanged() but it still happens.. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

Fagment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class YourPlanFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_your_plan) {
    lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentYourPlanBinding
    private val sharedViewModel: WorkoutPlansViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    @Inject
    lateinit var dataStore: UserPreferencesRepo


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        binding = FragmentYourPlanBinding.bind(view)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)

        val toolbar = binding.yourPlanToolbar
        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

       

        val exerciseAdapter = DayListAdapter(DayListAdapter.OnClickListener {
            navigateTo(sharedViewModel.weekIndex, it.dayNumber)
        })

        exerciseAdapter.currentList.clear()
        exerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        binding.recyclerViewYourPlan.apply {
            adapter = exerciseAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            recycledViewPool.clear()
            removeAllViews()
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }



        if (!sharedViewModel.planGenerated) {
           // Here the data is generated
            sharedViewModel.onTriggerEvent(WorkoutPlansEvent.GetWorkoutPlanEvent)
        } else if (sharedViewModel.planGenerated) {
            sharedViewModel.onTriggerEvent(WorkoutPlansEvent.GetWeekEvent)
        }


        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                sharedViewModel.yourPlanState.collect { yourPlanState ->



                    when (yourPlanState.progressBarState) {
                        is ProgressBarState.Loading -> {
                            binding.progressBar.isVisible = true
                        }
                        is ProgressBarState.Idle -> {
                            binding.progressBar.isInvisible = true
                        }
                    }

                    exerciseAdapter.submitList(yourPlanState.planDays)

                }
            }
        }

    }


    private fun navigateTo(
        currentWeek: Int,
        dayNumber: Int,
    ) {
        val action =
            YourPlanFragmentDirections.actionYourPlanFragmentToYourDayFragment(
                currentWeek,
                dayNumber
            )
        navController.navigate(action)
    }


}
```

ListAdapter:

```
class DayListAdapter(private val onClickListener: OnClickListener) :
    ListAdapter<Day, DayListAdapter.DayViewHolder>(ExerciseComparator()) {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DayViewHolder {
        val binding = ListItemDayBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return DayViewHolder(binding)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DayViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentItem = getItem(position)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onClickListener.onClick(currentItem)
        }

        if (currentItem != null) {
            holder.bind(currentItem)
        }

    }

    class DayViewHolder(private val binding: ListItemDayBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(day: Day) {
            binding.apply {
                dayNumber = day.dayNumber.toString()
                executePendingBindings()
            }
        }

    }


    class ExerciseComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Day>() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Day, newItem: Day) =
            oldItem.dayNumber == newItem.dayNumber

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Day, newItem: Day) =
            oldItem == newItem
    }


    class OnClickListener(val clickListener: (day: Day) -> Unit) {
        fun onClick(day: Day) = clickListener(day)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happing because of the `activityViewModels()` that will preserve the viewmodel based on activity lifecycle. Either create `WorkoutPlansViewModel`  using `viewmodels()` or Try to clear the list from the `WorkoutPlansViewModel` when you are creating the fragment.

Comment: Damn! I didn't even think about that. Thanks so much!

Comment: This happens some time.